# Unable to use bonnie++ for measuring I/O performance

Tags: benchmark

To troubleshoot some performance issues, we want to do some FS benchmark assessment using bonnie++, but whenever I try to execute, it only prints the usage without actually running.

Can anyone please check and see if I missed anything obvious in the syntax?

Current RAM for system - 516829 M

OS - CentOS 6.8

/usr/sbin/bonnie++ -r 516829  -d /opt -s 1033658 -n 1 -f -b -u root:root

[image]

If I intentionally assign less value for "-s", it promptly complains, e.g.

```
    /usr/sbin/bonnie++ -r 516829  -d /opt -s 1033 -n 1 -f -b -u root:root
Using uid:0, gid:0. File size should be double RAM for good results, RAM is 516829M.
```

I have tried compiling bonnie++ from source as well as installing from yum but all showing same behavior.

Drive for which we would like to measure I/O performance is /opt which is on a SAN mount.

[image]

Thanks,

~ Abhi

Comment: I had never heard of bonnie++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this machine has 504 GB RAM it would need 1008 GB free space for the benchmark file and many many hours (maybe days) for the benchmarking process to complete.

`/opt/` doesn't have enough diskspace thus you need to limit the ramsize and the filesize to something like this:

```
# use only 16G of ram and 32G benchsize. 
bonnie++ -d /opt/ -r 16G -s 32G -n 1 -f -b -u root
```

Just in case I got it wrong and you've got 504 MB RAM (you wouldn't need the `-r` switch)

```
bonnie++ -d /opt/ -s 1G -n 1 -f -b -u root
```

From the man pages - check the **bold** parts.

> **-s** the size of the file(s) for IO performance measures in megabytes. (..) The
>   chunk-size is measured in bytes and **must be a power of two from 256 to
>   1048576**, the default is 8192. NB You can specify the size in
>   giga-bytes or the chunk-size in kilo-bytes if you add **g** or **k** to the
>   end of the number respectively. If the specified size is 0 then this
>   test will be skipped.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I was able to run bonnie++ with reduced ramsize / filesize.

Comment: Is there a chance that these results are inaccurate due to OS caching?

Comment: Yes, to prevent that, the dataset (`-s`) needs to bei greater than the RAM (`free -m`). 2x usually.

Comment: @MichaelD. if I have `-r 128 -s 256 -n 1024`, will OS caching effect still kick in?  Because I am not sure `bonnie++` can get around OS caching when the actual physical memory is way bigger (for example 16GB).  If yes, it seems like using `-r` to specify a smaller size of physical memory seems to just trick `bonnie++` to do the test but gives not so realistic result that includes the caching effect.  Thanks!

Comment: @HCSF add `-b` for no write buffering.

Comment: @MichaelD. got it.  how about linux page cache (mainly for reading)?